# Change letter color of a text based on scroll position with React and Framer Motion

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I want to change the color of each letter of a text based on the scroll position.

The animation is the same as here (scroll down to the "Precision" section):

https://www.polestar.com/us/polestar-1/

I use React and Framer Motion. I don't have much yet, that's the only one so far.

https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-kare-khlt5f?file=/src/Example.js

Does anyone have a solution / idea how I can animate the individual letters?

Answer (score 0):

App.js

```
import Example from "./Example";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Example />
    </div>
  );
}
```

style.css

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.section__wrapper {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.section__title {
  font-size: 72px;
}
```

example.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useScroll, useMot } from "framer-motion";

export default function Example() {
  const targetRef = useRef(null);

  const str = "Here is some text that should be animated";
  const [a, setA] = useState(); //the string display in div
  const [myScroll, setMyScroll] = useState(0); //scrool position
  const [myColor, setMyColor] = useState(0);
  //set ref scroll position by document onScroll
  const handleScroll = () => {
    setMyScroll(targetRef.current.scrollTop);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    //check after the ref exist
    if (targetRef.current) {
      //you can design your math
      const displayLength = Math.floor(
        ((str.length + 10) * targetRef.current.scrollTop) /
          targetRef.current.scrollHeight
      );
      const displayColor = 255-Math.floor(
        (200 * targetRef.current.scrollTop) / targetRef.current.scrollHeight
      );

      // console.log(
      //   Math.floor(
      //     (str.length * targetRef.current.scrollTop) /
      //       targetRef.current.scrollHeight
      //   )
      // );
      // console.log(Math.floor(100*targetRef.current.scrollTop /
      // targetRef.current.scrollHeight));

      //set A as the "cool string"
      setA(str.substring(0, displayLength));
      //set color as the "cool color"
      setMyColor(displayColor);
    }
  }, [myScroll]);

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="section__wrapper"
        ref={targetRef}
        onScroll={() => {
          handleScroll();
        }}
      >
        <div>
          {/* scroll content */}
          <div className="section__title">1</div>
          <div className="section__title">2</div>
          <div className="section__title">3</div>
          <div className="section__title">4</div>
          <div className="section__title">5</div>
          <div className="section__title">6</div>
          <div className="section__title">7</div>
          <div className="section__title">8</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* display the string */}
      <div
        className="section__title"
        style={{ color: `rgb(${myColor},${myColor},${myColor})` }}
      >
        {a}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I am not good at the css, so i let it be easier. I change your code a lots and cleaner. I just focus on the scroll top ,height and "cool string". That's it.

Comment: Thank you but thats not quite what i want to achieve. Again look at the link i provided : https://www.polestar.com/us/polestar-1/
I definitely want to use **position sticky** . Also i want the color to change for example from white to blue immediately. In your example it looked like the opacity changes

Comment: sorry, i know what you talk about now... my work is not about software, and i also had tried use other package about css and animate. i couldn't find enough info to fully use the package. so i finded other way to get the same goals. the packages usually not enough for us and we also learn how to exend the packages... Fighting e e oh

Comment: example is not opacity...
you can try color: `rgb(${myColor},${myColor},255)`...

you need to get sreen height and the particular position ...
pos 100px let the div with css fixed upper layer...
pos 300px let the div dissapear...
100 to 300 that the str change...